# Layout below Fragment not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the follwing layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username: " />
</LinearLayout>
```

Programatically I'm replacing the view "content" with my Fragment:

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kwiz_game, container, false);
    contentView = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    currentFragment = new KwizCardBackFragment(android.R.drawable.btn_plus);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,
            currentFragment);
```

However the fragment is taking all the space and the Layout with the TextView is not shown.

I also tried to use RelativeLayouts with alignParentBottom=true and other stuff...

View of the Fragment which replaces the content:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_kwiz_item" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

OnCreateView of the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_back, container,
            false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    if (drawable != null) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    } else {
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
    }
    return view;
}
```

After hours of debugging I finally found the mistake... Some of my layouts had views with the id "content". I thought when I look for R.id.content that the "nearest" element will be used... that's not the case!

Thanks anyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your layout a little bit and this seems to achieve what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNav" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username: " />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And a small side note, I see you used `fill_parent` in your layout, but that's [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) since API level 8, so you should use `match_parent` instead :)
Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't work either... I don't know what I am might doing wrong.. because it seems so simple... I've added all the missing sourcecode to my question ;)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it... Perhaps you could upload your source code to Github so I could take a look at it?

Comment: I just wanted to implement a simple example for you and it works in there O_o. So I probably have some layout issues in my example. Thank you very much for your help! I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: After hours of debugging I finally found the mistake... Some of my layouts had views with the id "content". I thought when I look for R.id.content that the "nearest" element will be used... that's not the case!

Comment: Good to hear you found the bug! Do you mean that you were using the same id in the same layout? I'm using the same id in different layouts all the time and that never caused me any trouble...

Comment: yes I did. But the problem was that I'm replacing a specific view via a FragmentTransaction. This Transaction doesn't need any layout, just an id. And here it takes the id from the parent-layout ->  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,...)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `FrameLayout` as your fragment container, and put (and then replace) your fragments into that FrameLayout container.

Comment: I tried this - but there is no difference. My other layout is still gone when I add the fragment...